# General issue with BLE and Windows10

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

My goal is to write code that reads a characteristic out of a service. Simple as that.
My question is: Does Bluetooth LE have general issues with Win10? Im asking because i encountered erratic behaviour. For example:

1. I have a CC2650LP with Simple_Peripheral running (slightly changed to have only one Characteristic in Service 4 and being notificably and readable). When I start searching for devices i can see my device for about 10s. But only on Windows. When i use my phone, it is permanently visible as it should be.
2. My Ble scanner Software that i wrote is working on my desktop test PC, but not on another Desktop PC with the same settings. There, the characteristic is only read once and doesnt change in every read attempt.
   Im guessing there are general issues in Windows using BLE.
   What can i do to get my code working? Does anyone have a sample code in c++ that is working stable?

Comment: There is no such issue on Windows 10 if you use it correctly. However there are few flags that controls how read is executed. You can try GattClient from Bluetooth Framework (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) to test you device. Also refer to this artcile to find more details: https://www.btframework.com/ble.htm

Comment: Can you tell me what im doing wrong to get this kind of behaviour? I tried it with the unchanged Simple_peripheral and windows10, yet I see the device only for a couple of seconds. With my Smartphone i can see the device indefinitely.
I used the Code you send me the Link to and i could connect to my device, but here again it is only connectible for about 10s. 
The Link you sent me to read up on the issue is not helpful, because the explanations and the sample code is much different from my code. And i cant purchase 3rd party software.

Comment: @Mike And why can't I just pair the device with my PC and read whenever I want? That seems much better to me, i have to, for example, use the read function in a dll.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing wrong because I did not see your code. Because there is some tips you have to know before you can work with paired BLE devices on Windows 10 platform. And that depends on Win 10 build number cause some builds have bugs, other builds have other bugs.

Comment: Initially i use the code i found here:
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bad452cb-4fc2-4a86-9b60-070b43577cc9/is-there-a-simple-example-desktop-programming-c-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices?forum=wdk
for reading, which worked well on my test PC but not on other PCs, because, as you mentioned, different win10 builds have different bugs. But im really curious if there is a way to make the code work with this API.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. The first step is to switch to WinRT BLE API from Legacy one.